# Can't connect to MySQL database - It worked on local but not online

Tags: php, mysql

I can't connect to MySQL database, I triple checked that the credentials were correct and even contacted support from hosting: they told that it is probably a mistake in the MySql syntax- it works perfectly on local server but not online.

Do you see something suspicious?

```
  $DB_HOST="";
$DB_USER="";
$DB_PASSWORD="";
$DB_DATABASE="";
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "utente");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "password");
define("DB_DATABASE", "database");


$connessDB=mysqli_connect($DB_HOST,$DB_USER,$DB_PASSWORD,$DB_DATABASE);
$toDB=mysqli_query($connessDB,"INSERT INTO utenti (nome, eta, citta, paese, mail, password, username) VALUES ('nome','eta','citta','paese','mail','password','username')");
```

Comment: _define("DB_HOST", "localhost");_ you have to set with online host. You have to set with the config data for your online database

Comment: I replaced the actual credentials whit fake ones, just for the sake of the example, but I checked and they are 100% correct.

Comment: Display php and mysql errors and you would not be in the dark...

Comment: For testing, have you tried entering your connection details directly into mysqli_connect parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined constants with values, but still used variables for mysqli connection. Could you please try:

```
$connessDB=mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
```

Comment: I get :  Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045) .  Denied access

Comment: Have you got your credentials correctly? Is address of your mysql server really localhost?